# Using WS-Federation in .NET 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, token, ws-federation

Anyone please suggest an alternative to `SessionSecurityToken` in .NET  5.0.

Namespace - `System.IdentityModel.Tokens`

Earlier .NET framework with support for above assembly - 4.8

Comment: Why? What's wrong / what problem do you have with `SessionSecurityToken`?

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. Instead of trying to find equivalents, check how what you do is done in .NET Core. ASP.NET Identity changed a lot from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core

Comment: @marc_s we are migrating our code from dot net framework 4.8 to dot net 5.0. hence looking for alternative of SessionSecurityToken, which is being used in our existing code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, we have wsfedration with our own database structure, our own user management code. we don't want to use asp.net core identity and its related table structure.  <br/> <br/>  hence force to continue using wsfedration and custom session token management

Comment: So your real question is how to use WS-Federation in .NET Core. WS-* are web service standards, not table structures. .NET Core [supports WS-Federation already](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-6.0) by adding the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation` package. Whether you can use the old data or not, or how to migrate it, is another matter.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , Configured WS-Federation in our new app, by referring section =>  "WS-Federation without ASP.NET Core Identity sec" from link you shared. now i trying to find out the way to setup user token after user validation.  confused how it should be done. in 4.8 framework we had SessionSecurityToken for same